# Медиана массива и минимум суммы расстояний от `x` до элементов массива

Tags: математика

Для числовой последовательности `a(i), 1 <= i <= n` ищем минимум `sum(|x - a(i)|, 1 <= i <= n)`. Как доказать что одна из точек минимума - медиана `a`?

Comment: Был (и жив еще) [такой сайт](http://math.hashcode.ru/). Там спрашивать не пробовали?

Comment: [Геометрический центр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80), [The median minimizes the sum of absolute deviations (the ℓ1
norm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113270).

Answer (score 3):

## Доказательство для случая, когда все значения различны

Предполагается, что значения отсортированы по возрастанию.

Идея доказательства для **чётного числа точек** `n = 2*i`.

В этом случае `i`- номер точки, соответствующей медиане. Точнее, медиана находятся в интервале `[a(i), a(i+1))`.

Тогда для `x` из интервала `[a(i), a(i+1))` сумма выглядит так: половина слагаемых имеет вид `x-a(j)`, вторая половина `a(k) - x`. В сумме все `x` сокращаются, результат становится равным `S_0 = sum(a(k), k>i) - sum(a(j), j<=i)`

Сдвинем `x` в интервал `(a(i-1), a(i))`. Сумма станет равна `S_1 = sum(a(k), k>i+1) + a(i+1) - x + a(i) - x - sum(a(j), j<i) = S_0 + 2*a(i) - 2*x`

Так как `a(i) > x`, то `S_1 > S_0`. Если сдвинуть x ещё дальше, между `a(i-1)` и `a(i-2)` , то сумма будет `S_2 = S_1 + 2*a(i-1) - 2*x > S_1 > S_0`. Можно по индукции показать, что для каждого последующего интервала сумма будет возрастать.

Теперь сдвинем `x` в интервал `(a(i+1), a(i+2))`, тогда сумма будет равна `S_1' = sum(a(k), k>i+1) + x - a(i+1) + x - a(i) + sum(a(j), j<i) = S_0 - 2*a(i+1)+2*x`

Так как в этом случае `x > a(i+1)` то `S_1' > S_0`.

Если сдвинуть `x` дальше, между `a(i+2)` и `a(i+3)`, то сумма `S_2' = S_1' + 2*x - 2*a(i+2) > S_1' > S_0`. Опять индукцией можно показать, что по мере удаления от `a(i)` сумма будет только расти.

Следовательно, для чётного числа точек минимум достигается в точках интервала `(a(i), a(i+1))`, в том числе в медиане `(a(i) + a(i+1))/2)`

Теперь **нечётное число точек** `n = 2*i + 1`

Медиана равна `a(i+1)`. Сумма в медиане равна `S_0 = sum(a(k), k > i+1) + sum(a(j), j < i+1)`

Если `x` сдвинуть в интервал `(a(i), a(i+1))`, то сумма будет `S_1 = S_0 + a(i+1) - x > S_0`.

Если `x` сдвинуть в интервал `(a(i+1), a(i+2))`, то сумма будет `S_1' = S_0 + x - a(i+1) > S_0`.

Следовательно, для нечетного числа точек минимум достигается в медиане `a(i+1)`.

## Дополнение для случая, когда некоторые значения совпадают

Я оставлю текст ниже, он почти верный. Нужно отдельно рассмотреть вариант, когда медиана исходной последовательности не совпадает с медианой упрощённой последовательности.

Этот случай можно доказать как предыдущий, считая значения различными, но в сумме введя вес.

`S = sum(w(i)*|a(i)-x|, 1 <= i <=n)`, где `w(i)` - сколько раз повторяется `a(i)` в исходной последовательности. То есть все `w(i)` целые числа не меньше единицы.

Тогда при сдвигании x относительно медианы сумма будет увеличиваться не на значение `2*|x-a(i)|`, а на значение `2*w(i)*|x-a(i)| > 0`. То есть минимум в медиане.

Comment: Доказательство для случая когда все `a(i)` различны?

Comment: Да, в доказательстве предполагаются интервалы между `a(i)`. Если они совпадают, то нужно подумать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я добавил рассуждение, но в общем случае оно неверно. Нужно ещё подумать.