# Минимальное расстояние от m точек до n фиксированных точек на прямой

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, геометрия

Формальная постановка задачи следующая: даны N точек на прямой и последовательность `n1, n2, n3 ...` неубывающая. Расположите M точек так, чтобы сумма расстояний от ближайших точек `ni, n (i + 1) ...` до точки `mi` была минимальной для `i = 1 ... M`.

Неформальная интерпретация задачи: расположите M заправок на дороге так, чтобы N проживающих вдоль дороги людей тратили как можно меньше времени на то, чтобы добраться до заправки. Для одной АЗС условие простое: количество людей справа и слева от АЗС должно быть одинаковым.

M <= N

При большем количестве АЗС задача усложняется. Я привел [пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pZFG.png) размещения 3 заправок среди 10 точек. Каждый из них создает определенный сегмент, и на этом сегменте справа и слева от АЗС находится одинаковое количество людей.

Однако это не оптимальное решение. Мое предположение: для оптимальности требуется дополнительное условие: справа и слева должно быть одинаковое количество точек, по которым данная АЗС является ближайшей. [Пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pZFG.png) такого расположения показан на рисунке ниже, и действительно, сумма расстояний для такой ситуации меньше.

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как на этапе обустройства заправок проверить, какая точка будет ближайшей. Это [видно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pZFG.png) на первой картинке: мы расставляем точки так, чтобы с каждой стороны было одинаковое количество людей, но после расстановки оказывается, что ближайшая к ним АЗС не та, которую мы ожидали.

Comment: Отличная задача. Можно построить структуру которая за `M` считает сумму расстояний для заданного разбиения точек на `M` групп. После предобработки (за `N`) для двух групп (`M = 2`) задача решается двоичным поиском (`log N`).

Comment: Почему количество людей справа и слева должно быть одинаковым? Мне кажется, это уже неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот доказательство: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305702/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82-x-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0

Comment: Я не совсем понял ваш подход. Вы можете как-то его более многословно рассказать, пожалуйста?)

Comment: @Qwertiy изначально мне тоже это казалось неверно, как-то оно звучит контр-интуитивно

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на проверяющую систему если она есть.

Comment: хотелось бы обещанные фото и пример входных-выходных данных

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Теория

**Первый факт.** Если одна бензоколонка и сколько угодно клиентов, то одно из оптимальных решений - разместить бензоколонку в позиции медианы массива клиентов.

Тут есть два утверждения: во-первых, позиция бензоколонки совпадает с позицией оного из клиентов и, во-вторых, дан точный рецепт как эту позицию выбрать.

**Второй факт.** Если бензоколонок несколько, то всё равно есть оптимальное решение когда все бензоколонки совпадают с координатами клиентов.

### Простое решение

*Второй факт* позволяет решить задачу очень просто:

```
# xs - координаты клиентов, ys - координаты АЗС
# возвращает сумму наименьших расстояний от клиентов до АЗС
def dist(xs, ys):
    return sum(min(abs(x - y) for y in ys) for x in xs)

# xs - координаты клиентов, m - число АЗС
# возвращает минимальное расстояние от клиентов до АЗС и расположение АЗС
def baseline(xs, m):
    return min((dist(xs, ys), ys) for ys in itertools.combinations(xs, m))
```

Это решение имеет сложность `n * m * Cnk(n, m)`, где `n` - число клиентов (`len(xs)`), `Cnk` - "це из эн по ка" - количество комбинаций размера `k` из множества размера `n`.

Первые два множителя - время вычисления `dist`, последний - время перебора комбинаций (АЗС ставятся различным клиентам).

Оптимизировать не буду, это решение нужно только для тестирования.

### Рекурсивное решение задачи

Движемся в сторону динамического программирования. Чтобы решить задачу для `m` колонок надо разбить клиентов на две группы. Правой группе назначается одна колонка, левой группе `m - 1` колонка. Из всех таких разбиений требуется выбрать минимум. Для простоты эта функция возвращает только сумму расстояний, расположение АЗС не сохраняется:

```
@functools.cache
def recursive(xs, m):
    if m == 1:
        ys = xs[len(xs) // 2],
        return dist(xs, ys)

    return min(
        recursive(xs[:j], m - 1) + recursive(xs[j:], 1)
        for j in range(m - 1, len(xs))
    )
```

Сложность `n * (n * n * m)`. Левое слагаемое - вычисление растояний для случая одной колонки, правое слагаемое - сложность рекурсии. Мы заполняем таблицу размером `n * m`. Каждая ячейка требует `n` операций для заполнения. От одного множителя `n` можно избавится. Об этом ниже.

### Быстрое вычисление суммы расстояний до одной колонки

Даны координаты клиентов `xs` в неубывающем порядке. Из них выбирается подсписок `xs[j1:j2]`. Требуется найти наилучшее положение одной АЗС и сосчитать сумму расстояний до неё.

Из *первого факта* следует что АЗС надо поставить в медиану `xs[(j1 + j2) // 2]`. Вычислить сумму расстояний до неё можно за `O(j2 - j1)`. Есть способ вычисления этой суммы за `O(1)`.

Считаются кумулятивные суммы для `xs`. С их помощью расстояние вычисляется за константу. Код не самый приятный, извините.

```
def make_min_dist1(xs):

    def accumulate(a):
        s = 0
        yield s
        for v in a:
            s += v
            yield s

    sums = tuple(accumulate(xs))

    def min_dist1(j1, j2):
        assert j1 < j2
        j = (j1 + j2) // 2
        y = xs[j]

        # hi_dist = (sums[j2] - sums[j]) - (j2 - j) * y
        # lo_dist = (j - j1) * y - (sums[j] - sums[j1])
        # return lo_dist + hi_dist
        return -((j1 + j2) % 2) * y + sums[j2] + sums[j1] - 2 * sums[j]

    return min_dist1
```

### Динамическое программирование

Динмамическое программирование не отличается от предложенного [Zergatul](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1339903/416121). Кеш устроен сложнее и компактнее, вычисление расстояний для одной колонки сделано за константу. Вычисляется и расстояние и расположение АЗС. Код очень сложный, ещё раз извините:

```
def dynamics(xs, m):

    min_dist1 = make_min_dist1(xs)

    n = len(xs)

    if m == 1:
        return min_dist1(0, n), (xs[n // 2], )

    # min_dist(i, j) best solution is in cache[i - 1][j - i + 1]
    cache = []

    def min_dist(i, j):
        # cache[i - 2][j - i + 1] stores best solution for min_dist(i - 1, k) task
        return min(
            (cache[i - 2][k - i + 1][0] + min_dist1(k, j), k)
            for k in range(i - 1, j)
        )
    
    # min_dist(1, j) best solution is in cache[0][j]
    cache.append(tuple((min_dist1(0, j), 0) for j in range(1, n - m + 2)))
    for i in range(2, m):
        # min_dist(i, j) best solution is in cache[i - 1][j - i + 1]
        cache.append(tuple(min_dist(i, j) for j in range(i, n - m + i + 1)))

    d, k = min_dist(m, n)

    def min_point(k):
        yield xs[(k + n) // 2]
        for i in reversed(range(1, m)):
            _, k1 = cache[i - 1][k - i]
            yield xs[(k1 + k) // 2]
            k = k1

    return d, tuple(min_point(k))[::-1]
```

Сложность этого решения `n * n * m`.

Тест на параболе - 500 клиентов, 10 АЗС выполняется за 0.7 секунды:

```
print(*dynamics(tuple(i * i for i in range(500)), 10))
```

> 2803416 (2500, 17689, 36864, 59049, 84100, 110889, 139129, 168921,
> 199809, 232324)

Answer (score 6):

Решение при помощи динамики за `O(N^3)`. `calc_median_distance` можно предрасчитать для всех возможных значений заранее. Я уверен что есть более быстрое решение, но это должно быть довольно простое.

```
array = [2, 8, 14, 17, 19, 20, 24, 30, 35, 39]
n = len(array)
m = 3

# считает сумму растояний до медианы на подмассиве [fr, to)
def calc_median_distance(fr, to):
    median_index = (fr + to) // 2
    distance = 0
    for i in range(fr, to):
        distance += abs(array[i] - array[median_index])
    return distance

# d[i1][i2] - лучшее решение (сумма растояний) для точек [0..i1) и i2 заправок
# изначально заполнен каким-то большим значением
# заведомо больше любого возможного решения
maxr = 1000000000
d = [[maxr] * (m + 1) for _ in [0] * (n + 1)]

# s - двумерный массив такого же самого размера
# s[i1][i2] - это длина последнего отрезка для решения d[i1][i2]
# используется для восстановления решения в конце
s = [[0] * (m + 1) for _ in [0] * (n + 1)]

d[0][0] = 0 # решение длиной 0, для 0 заправок

for i2 in range(1, m + 1):
    for i1_from in range(i2 - 1, n):
        for i1_to in range(i1_from + 1, n + 1):

            # решение для подотрезка [0..i1_from) и (i2 - 1) заправок
            prev = d[i1_from][i2 - 1]
            if prev == maxr:
                continue

            # решение для подотрезка [0..i1_to) и i2 заправок
            # строится как {[0..i1_from) для (i2 - 1)} + {[i1_from..i2_to) для 1}
            next = prev + calc_median_distance(i1_from, i1_to);
            if next < d[i1_to][i2]:
                d[i1_to][i2] = next
                s[i1_to][i2] = i1_to - i1_from

print("Best distance = " + str(d[n][m]))

segments = []
i1 = n
i2 = m
while i2 > 0:
    seg = s[i1][i2]
    segments.insert(0, seg)
    i1 -= seg
    i2 -= 1

print("Segments = " + ' '.join(str(x) for x in segments))
```

Comment: Во-первых, проверьте этот алгоритм на m=1 :) Во-вторых, он не проходит тесты, программа выдаёт ошибку, где-то там выход за границы массива скорее всего.

Comment: @OlegChaika слушайте, мне нужно написать рабочее полностью протестированное решение за вас, или просто помочь с решением?

Comment: @OlegChaika во-вторых, на каких конкретно тестах моя программа выдает ошибку? почему в меня она работает и при `m=1`, и при `n=1`? Может вы просто даже не попытались понять что она делает?

Comment: Я проверил ваш код. Работает правильно на всех моих тестах. Подгонять пришлось только максимум на примерах со степенями двойки.